# I was told Git SSH is not interactive?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, repository, putty

Before I even discovered [this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/), I had already completed many of the steps required. This included making a keypair and inserting the key on the gitlab account through the website.

On Windows 10, using the Putty GUI, I selected my private key, and then I SSH connected to: git@gitlab.com:mycompanyname-go/fuzzing.git

A console window appears and the following is displayed:

```
Server refused to allocate pty.
Welcome to gitlab, @MyUsernameHere
```

Why does my SSH console window close before I can type any commands? I assume it is something to do with the "*server refused to allocate pty" part*?

A developer I work with said that this is happening "*because gitlab is not interactive like SSH*", and that I need to connect another way. If this is the case I hope someone can please list step by step how to do this, because it is driving me mad.

Comment: git uses SSH just for pushing/pulling, not for running commands.

Answer (score 2):

`git clone git@gitlab.com:example.com/fuzzing.git`. ssh was built for shell access but it was built so well it's the foundation for vastly more than that.

> Why does my SSH console window close before I can type any commands?

Because when you use the `ssh` command yourself, by default it asks for plain shell access. Gitlab sees that and assumes you're just checking whether your key's set up properly. The "shell" it runs for the `git` user with that key spits a welcome message and exits, so now you know it knows your name.

When *Git* runs ssh, and yes it does run the system's ssh, it asks the ssh server at the other end to run a git command as the shell. For fetch (clone is a convenience command for init-and-fetch-and-checkout), that's `git-upload-pack`, for push, it's `git-receive-pack`.

edit: for anyone who wants to see all the gory details, try

```
GIT_TRACE=true GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true git command here
```